# Python: flatten an XML document (remove newlines)

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, newline

Python newbie here.

I want to flatten XML documents. For example, I want to convert this:

```
<Document>
    Hello, World
</Document>
```

to this:

```
<Document>    Hello, World</Document>
```

I wrote a Python program, flatten.py, to do the flattening:

```
import sys
import stdio

s = ''
while True:
   t = sys.stdin.readline()
   if not t:
      break
   s = s + t

stdio.write(s.rstrip('\r\n'))
```

I created an exe for flatten.py. Then I opened a DOS window and typed:

```
type input.xml | flatten
```

(input.xml is the XML shown above)

Here is the output:

```
<Document>
    Hello, World
</Document>
```

Sadly, the XML is not flattened. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: rstrip only removes character from the end, your string is like "a\nb\nc"

Comment: Do you want to remove all newline characters from the whole file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose :

```
  import sys
  import stdio

  s = ''
  while True:
      t = sys.stdin.readline()
      if not t:
          break
      s = s + t.rstrip('\r\n')

  stdio.write(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("".join(line.rstrip() for line in sys.stdin))
```

Answer (score 1):

this is one way of doing it

```
import sys

s = ''
while True:
    t = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not t:
        break
    s = s + t

print ''.join(s.splitlines())
```